# Reading output from TCPFlow with Perl Script

Tags: perl

I have been playing around with TCPFlow to look at telnet traffic.  What I would like to do is have the output from TCPFlow redirected to a Perl Script that watches for the phrase "Password:" then prints out the following password to a terminal window or separate file. How do I redirect the output from TCPFlow to my Perl Script then constantly search it to find the "Password" string?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you open TCPFlow as a subprocess `open(my $infh, "<", "TCPFlow args|")`, you can get its output as a filehandle. The [manual page](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) has more.

Comment: You may also want to look at [`perldoc perlopentut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html)

Comment: humm...Im not sure how this would work.  For tcpflow I can either write it to the console window or to a file.  #tcpflow -c -s is what prints it out to the console window.  So, it would be open(my $infh, "<", "tcpflow -c -s|")?

Comment: what if I did open(FH, "tcpflow -c -s |");

Comment: Would I be able to constantly search that file handle to look for a string?

Comment: That call to open looks ok, What you can do in that case is `while (m $line = <FH>) { dostuffwith($line); }`